# Finding the path of the current user

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to open a file from Java in Ubuntu using FileInputStream.Now my problem is,how can i find the path of the current user as `/home/"currentuser"/myfile.xxx`?? Normally i use the path as a string since i know the current user.
Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user's home directory can be retrieved via

```
String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

See [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)